# Python - optimizing math equation for a simple guessing game score calc

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization, equation

I'm trying to create a equation similar to a messy block of code I've made, to calculate the score based on the amount of guesses a player took in a guessing game.

The player has 10 tries. For every unsuccesful try, the score multiplication is reduced by x. 
So the more tries, the less will the score be factored by.

I've tried counting the length of the guesses list that contain the amount of tries, but this works in reverse of what I want. It gives the player a higher score the more he tries he has used.

I've tried using len(guesses[::-1]), but that does the same... obviously as it still counts e.g 10 tries.

Any ideas how to do this? I suspect a for loop, but I haven't been able to make anything close to working.

Basically what I'm searching for is an equation or mathematical expression, not so much a list, dict, etc way of doing it.

E.g something linear like:

```
Prize = bet * (reversedGuesses * 
1.25) 
# so that if it took 1 try = 12.5
# and if it took 10 tries = 1.25
```

My current messy, unopptimized block of code:

```
if tries == 10:
    prize = bet * 7
elif tries == 9:
    prize = bet * 6
elif tries == 8:
    prize = bet * 5
elif tries == 7:
    prize = bet * 3.5
elif tries == 6:
    prize = bet * 2.75
elif tries == 5:
    prize = bet * 2.50
elif tries == 4:
    prize = bet * 2.25
elif tries == 3:
    prize = bet * 2.0
elif tries == 2:
    prize = bet * 1.75
elif tries == 1: 
    prize = bet * 1.5
```

The above obviously works, but I'm sure it can be done way more efficiently...

I'm new to python, so an explanation would be awesome too!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried using len(guesses[::-1]), but that does the same... obviously as it still counts e.g 10 tries.

The problem with this approach is that if you reverse the list, and ask how long it is, it is going to be exactly as long as the original list.

> Basically what I'm searching for is an equation or mathematical expression, not so much a list, dict, etc way of doing it.

You could divide by the number of guesses they used. Something like:

```
Prize = bet / len(guesses)
```

You could make the prize reduce by 10% for every wrong guess:

```
Prize = bet * ((1 - 0.10) ** len(guesses))
```

You could make the prize go down to 0 after 10 wrong guesses, and go down by the same amount each time in between:

```
guesses_left = max(0, 10 - len(guesses))
Prize = bet * guesses_left
```

> I'm new to python, so an explanation would be awesome too!

If you multiply by the length of the list, then the prize is going to get bigger the longer that they play, which is the opposite of what you're looking for.